# Create a view from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with records like

[image]

and so on.
The sample record in JSON format

```
[{
 empId:'123',
 empName:'Emp1',
 shiftHours:'Regular'
},
{
 empId:'123',
 empName:'Emp1',
 shiftHours:'Morning'
}
]
```

Basically an employee can work in regular shift(9am-6 pm) or morning shift (6 am-3 pm) or night shift (9pm-6 am). The hours are just example here but the idea is that the working hours are categorized in 3 shifts. I want to create a view with flat structure per employee like this

[image]

and so on.

I am trying to understand what's the best way to create such a flat view (coming from SQL background, I think a procedure/function has to be written) but not sure what's the best way to do so using No-Sql (Mongo db).
Any suggestions?

Comment: `"$group"` on `"EmpId"` and accumulate the `"Shift-Hours"`.

Comment: Provide sample documents in json format and please show the current attempt you are having.

Comment: @rickhg12hs any reference material. I read some articles but it mostly talks about creating a view with 1->1 mapping between rows

Comment: @ray question amended to show the JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$group` by `empId` and conditionally `$sum` by `shiftHours`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$empId",
      empName: {
        $first: "$empName"
      },
      Morning: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$shiftHours",
                "Morning"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      Regular: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$shiftHours",
                "Regular"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      Evening: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$shiftHours",
                "Evening"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Morning: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$Morning",
              0
            ]
          },
          "Y",
          "N"
        ]
      },
      Regular: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$Regular",
              0
            ]
          },
          "Y",
          "N"
        ]
      },
      Evening: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$Evening",
              0
            ]
          },
          "Y",
          "N"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BX69nb9Y0jZ)